# How can I assign the value returned from an insert query to a variable in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function in Postgres which does a simple insert, and i want the id of the insert for later usage. But I'm being said 'Synatx error near (' at line `question_key := INSERT INTO QUESTIONS(question, status, questionword) values (in_question, 'unanswered', in_questionword) RETURNING q_key;`
Is this the right way to assign?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_new_record_hackathon(
    in_keywords character varying[],
    in_question text,
    in_questionword character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
i integer;
question_key integer;
keyword_key integer;
BEGIN
question_key := INSERT INTO QUESTIONS(question, status, questionword) values (in_question, 'unanswered', in_questionword) RETURNING q_key;

FOREACH i in ARRAY in_keywords
LOOP
keyword_key :=  INSERT INTO keywords(keyword) VALUES (in_keywords[i]) RETURNING k_key;
INSERT INTO qnkeywordmap(q_key, k_key) values (question_key, keyword_key)
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: you don't need a loop for that. You don't even need PL/pgSQL for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way it to use `INSERT ... RETURNING` with the `INTO` clause:

```
INSERT INTO keywords ...
RETURNING k_key INTO keyword_key;
```